# 54.148.143.49 connection has timed out

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just set up a new EC2 Linux instance, 
I assigned an elastic ip to the instance so it should be reachable.

No problems on my other 2 instances.

ip is 54.148.143.49 and I can not verify that my apache is running I am following, this guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Security group was mal configured.

Added HTTP and HTTPS.